# rip DVD and overlay only "single" subtitle track, using VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I'm using these tutorials to rip a DVD into a video file (with a subtitle track "burned" or permanently overlayed into the video).

https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-rip-DVDs-for-free-with-VLC/

https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/vlc-subtitles.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0NzMlhnzQQ

The Problem: the process produces a video containing all the subtitle tracks (in various languages) simultaneously "burned in" or overlayed onto the video.

How do I get only a single subtitle track "burned in"?

(And yes, I do choose the correct subtitle track before starting the entire process. When I do that, it generates this code: `sub-track=0` under "Menu>Media>Open Disc>Disc>Edit Options")

Comment: Please don't add the answer into the question body. Post it separately - that way you can mark it as 'accepted'. Answering your own question & accepting your own answer is perfectly fine & sits well with the overall Stack Exchange ethos.